# How does arrive at the closed form expression of ap^1 + ap^2 + ... + ap^k?

Tags: geometric-series, geometric-progressions

How is the following true? Taken from [here](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000051060/0000000000058a56) under ANALYSIS, Large data set.
$$ap^1 + ap^2 + ap^3 + ... + ap^k = a\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}$$
I just can't seem to arrive at the right-hand side. Thanks!

Also please note that this is my first question on here. If this is a stupid question to ask, I'm truly sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $a+ap+ap^2+\ldots=\frac a{1-p}$ for $|p|<1$. And, $$(a+ap+ap^2+\ldots)-(ap^{k+1}+ap^{k+2}+\ldots)=a+ap+\ldots+ap^k$$

Comment: But the summation for k terms is valid for all $p \ne 1$, not just $|p| < 1$.

Comment: True, but not my derivation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the formula the text of the question asks us to verify is, in fact, wrongly stated; the correct version is

$a + ap^1 + ap^2 + \ldots ap^k = a \dfrac{p^{k + 1} - 1}{p - 1}, \tag 0$

seen as follows:

Holding the factor $a$ in abeyance for a moment, we have

$(p - 1) \displaystyle \sum_0^k p^i = p \sum_0^k p^i - \sum_0^k p^i$
$= \displaystyle \sum_0^k p^{i + 1} - \sum_0^k p^i = \sum_1^{k + 1} p^i - \sum_0^k p^i$
$= p^{k + 1} + \displaystyle \sum_1^k p^i - \sum_1^k p^i - p^0 = p^{k + 1} - 1; \tag 1$

thus,

$\displaystyle \sum_0^k p^i = \dfrac{p^{k + 1} - 1}{p - 1}; \tag 2$

re-introducing the factor $a$ *via* multiplication on both sides thus yields

$\displaystyle \sum_0^k a p^i = a\dfrac{p^{k + 1} - 1}{p - 1}, \tag 3$

which is simply another way of writing (1), the desired result.

Comment: So then ap^1 + ap^2 + ... + ap^k = a(p^(k+1) - 1)/(p-1) - a? Does that mean the explanation provided in the link is wrong? @RobertLewis

Comment: @MuratGoksel:  I believe the answer to your first question is yes; as for the second, to which link do you refer?

Comment: @RobetLewis this link: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000051060/0000000000058a56. If you go to ANALYSIS tab, you'll see an explanation given under Large dataset. I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @MuratGoksel:  I'll try to look at/think about it and get back to you when I've go a little time.  Cheers!

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it! @RobertLewis